# Elasticsearch query through Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am using the following elasticsearch query to fetch the details,

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                    {"match": {
                        "val": "GET"
                    }}]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is working fine and given the result as required.

I want to execute the same query through java and get the same results and tried the following,

```
 getClient().prepareSearch(esIndex)
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(QUERY)).execute().actionGet();
```

It is not returning the data and throw some query format wrong exception as well.

Is there any Java API available using which the same query can be executed?

**NOTE**: There is a possibility available to create the boolquery and aggregation builders in java api and execute the same. I am just curious to find a way to execute this query directly through elasticsearch java api

Comment: Hmm. Don't you think the content of that query that you give to your Java code would matter? Especially given the fact that java tells you that that query is not well formatted? So... Why is that part missing from your question?

Comment: I have passed the same query which is worked well through the HTTP POST.

Comment: You are using a query string constant. And you claim what is written in that string. Instead of just showing us that code.

Comment: Which version of Es you are using ?

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use the Query String Query, your query has to follow [Query String Syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax):

```
getClient().prepareSearch(esIndex)
           .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("val: \"GET\""))
           .execute()
           .actionGet();
```

As already stated, you should construct your query by using the provided QueryBuilders instead of strings. This will keep your code clean and readable even for complex queries.

```
getClient().prepareSearch(esIndex)
           .setQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                                  .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("val", "GET"))
           .execute()
           .actionGet();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
BoolQueryBuilder bool       =   boolQuery();

bool.must(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()); 
    bool.filter(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("Val", "GET")));

    AggregationBuilder agg = AggregationBuilders.terms("").field("");

    SearchResponse reponse =    getClient().prepareSearch().setIndices("indexName").setTypes("indexType")
                .setQuery(bool).addAggregation(agg).execute().actionGet();
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use boolQuery() when you construct your QueryBuilder:

```
QueryBuilder qb = boolQuery()
            .must(termQuery("content", "test1"))
            .must(termQuery("content", "test4"))
            .mustNot(termQuery("content", "test2"))
            .should(termQuery("content", "test3"))
            .filter(termQuery("content", "test5"));
```

Official docs:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-compound-queries.html